# Query filtering by date and time in one column and milliseconds in another

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
Time_Stamp ,Time_Stamp_ms
'2014-04-11 13:33:24', '879', '5555', '4444', '3333', '2222', '1111', '123', '1', 'text'
'2014-04-11 13:33:24', '899', '5555', '4444', '3333', '2222', '1111', '123', '2', 'text'
'2014-04-11 13:33:24', '919', '5555', '4444', '3333', '2222', '1111', '123', '3', 'text'
'2014-04-11 13:33:24', '939', '5555', '4444', '3333', '2222', '1111', '123', '4', 'text'
'2014-04-11 13:33:24', '959', '5555', '4444', '3333', '2222', '1111', '123', '5', 'text'
'2014-04-11 13:33:24', '979', '5555', '4444', '3333', '2222', '1111', '123', '6', 'text'
'2014-04-11 13:33:24', '999', '5555', '4444', '3333', '2222', '1111', '123', '7', 'text'
'2014-04-11 13:33:25', '19', '5555', '4444', '3333', '2222', '1111', '123', '8', 'text'
'2014-04-11 13:33:25', '39', '5555', '4444', '3333', '2222', '1111', '123', '9', 'text'
'2014-04-11 13:33:25', '59', '5555', '4444', '3333', '2222', '1111', '123', '10', 'text'
'2014-04-11 13:33:25', '79', '5555', '4444', '3333', '2222', '1111', '123', '11', 'text'
'2014-04-11 13:33:25', '99', '5555', '4444', '3333', '2222', '1111', '123', '12', 'text'
```

As you can see I have a `Time_Stamp` (datetime) and a `Time_Stamp_ms` (Integer) in separate columns due to MySQL Server 5.5. My primary keys are `Time_Stamp` and `Time_Stamp_ms`.

I want to filter everything that happened
between **2014-04-11 13:33:24.879** and **2014-04-11 13:33:25.79**
and show me all data.

I've tried several variants:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (concat(Time_Stamp,'.',Time_Stamp_ms)
BETWEEN '2014-04-11 13:33:24.879' AND '2014-04-11 13:33:25.79');
```

Also

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE ( '2014-04-11 13:33:24' < Time_Stamp
OR ('2014-04-11 13:33:24' = Time_Stamp AND '879' <= Time_Stamp_ms))
AND ( '2014-04-11 13:33:25' < Time_Stamp
OR ('2014-04-11 13:33:25' = Time_Stamp AND Time_Stamp_ms < '79'))
```

And last but not least:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE ( '2014-04-11 13:33:24' < Time_Stamp
OR ('2014-04-11 13:33:24' = Time_Stamp AND 879 <= Time_Stamp_ms))
AND ( '2014-04-11 13:33:25' < Time_Stamp
OR ('2014-04-11 13:33:25' = Time_Stamp AND Time_Stamp_ms < 79))
```

This last one gives me results which do not make sense (for example it shows me data from 2014-04-11 13:33:27)

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: shouldn't you write this `'2014-04-11 13:33:25' < Time_Stamp` as `'2014-04-11 13:33:25' > Time_Stamp` instead..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so maybe just because you mistakenly typed the operator..

try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE ( '2014-04-11 13:33:24' < Time_Stamp
OR ('2014-04-11 13:33:24' = Time_Stamp AND 879 <= Time_Stamp_ms))
AND ( '2014-04-11 13:33:25' > Time_Stamp //--> here
OR ('2014-04-11 13:33:25' = Time_Stamp AND Time_Stamp_ms < 79))
```

Comment: WOW, Im sorry....What a dumb mistake:

'SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE ( '2014-04-11 13:33:24' < Time_Stamp
OR ('2014-04-11 13:33:24' = Time_Stamp AND 879 <= Time_Stamp_ms))
AND ( '2014-04-11 13:33:25' > Time_Stamp 
OR ('2014-04-11 13:33:25' = Time_Stamp AND Time_Stamp_ms <= 79))'

Thank you

Comment: C# seems to discard the seconds in Time_Stamp when returning all the data from the table...

Answer (score 0):

If `Time_Stamp_ms` stores value for *milliseconds*, then

```
select 
  @ms:=Time_Stamp_ms as millis, 
  @ms*1000 as micros, 
  cast( @ms/1000 as decimal(8,6) ) seconds
from my_table
limit 2
```

may result

```
+--------+--------+----------+
| millis | micros | seconds  |
+--------+--------+----------+
|    879 | 879000 | 0.879000 |
|     79 |  79000 | 0.079000 |
+--------+--------+----------+
```

But you were trying to concat like `ts + .879` and `ts + .79`.
This was wrong.

---

I have following solution compiled.
( I didn't check this yet. SQLFiddle is down :(( )

Convert the `milli seconds` value into `microseconds` and use with `time_stamp` column to fetch records between desired time stamp values.

Following query should ease your problem in comparing the dates and milliseconds.

```
select * from table_name
 where `Time_Stamp` + interval ( `Time_Stamp_ms` * 1000 ) microsecond
       between '2014-04-11 13:33:24.879'  -- <--- .879
           and '2014-04-11 13:33:25.079'; -- <--- .079
```

Comment: Your first query gave the expected result. The second did not return anything...at all.